# How to use partitionBy and orderBy together in Pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to split sessions from lastfm dataset, following the answer from 
https://www.arundhaj.com/blog/calculate-difference-with-previous-row-in-pyspark.html

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import countDistinct, count, lag, to_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.window import Window


spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("SampleAPP") \
        .config("spark.executor.memory", "4g") \
        .getOrCreate()

fname = "inputFile.tsv"
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', delimiter='\t').load(fname)
df = df.selectExpr("_c0 as userid", "_c1 as timestamp", "_c2 as artid", "_c3 as artname", "_c4 as traid",
                       "_c5 as traname")

df = df.withColumn('new_ts', df.timestamp.astype('Timestamp').cast("long"))
my_window = Window.partitionBy("userid").orderBy("new_ts")
df = df.withColumn("prev_value", lag(df.new_ts).over(my_window))
df.show()
```

but getting the following error: **py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o56.showString**,

the dataset looks like this,

```
+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|     userid|           timestamp|               artid|        artname|               traid|             traname|    new_ts|
+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|user_000001|2009-05-04T23:08:57Z|f1b1cf71-bd35-4e9...|      Deep Dish|                null|Fuck Me Im Famous...|1241478537|
|user_000001|2009-05-04T13:54:10Z|a7f7df4a-77d8-4f1...|           坂本龍一|                null|Composition 0919 ...|1241445250|
|user_000001|2009-05-04T13:52:04Z|a7f7df4a-77d8-4f1...|           坂本龍一|                null|Mc2 (Live_2009_4_15)|1241445124|
|user_000001|2009-05-04T13:42:52Z|a7f7df4a-77d8-4f1...|           坂本龍一|                null|Hibari (Live_2009...|1241444572|
+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

any help on how to solve would be really appreciated.

Full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 42, in <module>
    df.show()
  File "path/to//venvs/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 350, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "path/to//venvs/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "path/to//venvs/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "path/to//venvs/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o57.showString.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.window.WindowExec.doExecute(WindowExec.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BaseLimitExec$class.inputRDDs(limit.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalLimitExec.inputRDDs(limit.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

dataframe seems to work after the following line,

```
df = df.withColumn('new_ts', df.timestamp.astype('Timestamp').cast("long"))
```

[image]

SOLUTION: I tried to fix this in my local env but unfortunately, I couldn't.

used docker image from https://github.com/MinerKasch/training-docker-pyspark and executed in Jupyter Notebook and the same code works.

Many thanks for all the help.

Comment: You need to include the full error traceback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PySpark python issue: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o48.showString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761758/pyspark-python-issue-py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o48-showstr)

Comment: Hi @Sharath: I have updated the question with full traceback, and I couldn't find any messages related to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: I have also updated the full code, in which I have allocated 4g memory and the error still persists

Comment: It is also not related to memory issues, but to some Argument which you performed in advance

Comment: @gaw: Thaks for the comment, Can you please explain a bit more, that is my entire code and I'm not doing any operations before that.

Comment: Did the code ever run? And have you been able to read the csv with your command before? I usually use `spark.read.csv("/path/*", header="true", escape="\"", quote="\"", sep="\t", multiLine=True)`  I think you should use `sep="\t"` instead of `delimiter="\t"`

Comment: @gaw: I can verify that reading file works as intended.

Comment: @gaw: when I tried your way of reading CSV file i'm getting the following error *py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.csv*

Comment: Can you leave out the unnecessary columns in the printing and re-add them one by one? I have a similar example file now with `userid` and `timestamp` and everything works. So maybe it is a problem in displaying a special character

Comment: @gaw: That didn't work as well, Finally changed my working environment from Docker image from https://github.com/MinerKasch/training-docker-pyspark and the code seems to work now. Probably something wrong with my dev environment in  my local machine

Answer (score 0):

Error is not with syntax of window partitioning. Since spark does lazy evaluation, you are getting an error at show(). Meaning error can be any transformation that has been done till then.

But I suppose error is mostly caused by **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space** since partitioning is heavy memory operation. I suggest to read the full error traceback. If my prediction is right you should increase your memory to avoid this issue.

Comment: Just found a similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761758/pyspark-python-issue-py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o48-showstr

Comment: Hi @Sharath: I have updated the question with full traceback, and I couldn't find any messages related to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Ok. I just guessed the error might be Java heap space error as I don't have a full log before. By seeing the current log and other answers I guess the error is because of data in Timestamp column. To verify can you add `df.show()` after `df = df.withColumn('new_ts', df.timestamp.astype('Timestamp').cast("long"))` and comment the below code after that. If the issue still persists then the error is definitely with the data in Timestamp.

Comment: I can verify that df.show() works after typecasting, I have updated a picture in the question for your reference

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to reproduce your error. When I run the following code, which is pretty much all of your logic, I do not receive any errors:

```python
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1,datetime.date(2017, 4, 1)),(2,datetime.date(2017, 4, 2)),(3,datetime.date(2017, 4, 3)),(1,datetime.date(2017, 4, 2)),(1,datetime.date(2017, 4, 4)),                   
    ], ("_c0","_c1"))


test_df = test_df.selectExpr("_c0 as userid", "_c1 as timestamp")
test_df = test_df.withColumn('new_ts', test_df.timestamp.astype('Timestamp').cast("long"))
my_window = Window.partitionBy("userid").orderBy("new_ts")
test_df = test_df.withColumn("prev_value", lag(test_df.new_ts).over(my_window))
test_df.show()
```

Output:

```python
+------+----------+----------+----------+
|userid| timestamp|    new_ts|prev_value|
+------+----------+----------+----------+
|     1|2017-04-01|1491004800|      null|
|     1|2017-04-02|1491091200|1491004800|
|     1|2017-04-04|1491264000|1491091200|
|     3|2017-04-03|1491177600|      null|
|     2|2017-04-02|1491091200|      null|
+------+----------+----------+----------+
```

So my guess is that your problem is in your data and you have a special character in one of the files. I also recreated a small tsv-file and completely used your code which worked for me (see version 2).

Version 2:

```python
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', delimiter='\t').load("/home/spark/test.csv")
df = df.selectExpr("_c0 as userid", "_c1 as timestamp")

df = df.withColumn('new_ts', df.timestamp.astype('Timestamp').cast("long"))
my_window = Window.partitionBy("userid").orderBy("new_ts")
df = df.withColumn("prev_value", lag(df.new_ts).over(my_window))
df.show()
```

Output 2

```python
+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+
|  userid|           timestamp|    new_ts|prev_value|
+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+
|user_001|2009-05-04T13:52:04Z|1241445124|      null|
|user_001|2009-05-04T13:54:10Z|1241445250|1241445124|
|user_001|2009-05-04T23:08:57Z|1241478537|1241445250|
+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi @gaw: Many thanks for the response. I tried both versions of your code and the error still persists. Still trying to figure out what's causing it