# PySpark Join Error when using .show command?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to join two dataframes in pyspark. I created a unique key to do so. I keep getting an error which I do not understand.

Code used:

```
join = df.join(df2, on=['key'], how='inner')

join.show()
```

I checked the keys and there are correct, unique and there should be matches. The error I get is as follows:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling .showString.
```

If I use this code:

```
left_join = df.join(df2, df.key == df2.key, 'left')

left_join.show()
```

Also get an error: `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling .showString.`

If I remove the `.show()` command I don't get an error..? Anyone knows why this is and how I can solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your df and df1 looks like?  Schema wise and some example data as well.  Also have you try to do a show(1) to show just one item?  Typically you don't want to do a full show if the dataframe is very large, and just show a small number.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761758/pyspark-python-issue-py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o48-showstr

Comment: I solved the issue. The problem was the location of the java installation. Apparently it cannot be located in program files x86. Now that I did the installation somewhere else it works fine!