# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o130.showString. how to resolve this error

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, py4j

I am new to pyspark while running I start getting this error, which I don't get why it is coming?
error is: `*py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o130.showString*.`

Comment: Could you provide the code that is causing the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark python issue: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o48.showString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761758/pyspark-python-issue-py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o48-showstr)