# {Py4JJavaError}An error occurred while calling o339.save

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I trained Logistic regression model in pyspark but couldn't save the model.

```
Model = LogisticRegression(featuresCol='TF-IDF', labelCol='labels', maxIter=10)`
lr_model = Model.fit(train_data)`
type(lrmodel) /*<class pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel'>
lr_model.write().overwrite().save("MODEL_LR")
```

I'm facing error that

> {Py4JJavaError}An error occurred while calling o384.save.
> ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:   at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:1007)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:900)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1212)
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1306)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1306)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1288)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:978)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:660)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:700)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:699)
> at
>
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem....

I also tried lr_model.save("MODEL_LR") but same error throws.

Comment: This is a windows specific problem not a general spark problem. 
 The solution here will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48674945/3238085

Comment: @user238607 Thanks , but another exception shows that   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
{Py4JJavaError}An error occurred while calling o233.save.at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:106)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
 at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)

Comment: The Above issue resolved by import findspark ,findspark.init()

Comment: First I tried [stackoverflow.com/a/48674945/3238085](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761758/pyspark-python-issue-py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o48-showstr?rq=2) and Another exception thrown it was resolved by [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761758/pyspark-python-issue-py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o48-showstr?rq=2) and then how to close this issue

Comment: You can detail the steps in your answer and accept your own answer for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by following steps:

1. install microsoft visual c++ 2010 from this https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=26999
2. set Environmental variables, once pyspark environment setup completed.
3. when using IDE,
   use `import findspark findspark.init()`